# How can I get nth column of a dynamic range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get a filtered range by `=FILTER(A1:Z1000, $P1:$P1000="T1")`

This function will return a range of several rows and 26 columns.

But I only want the `A`, `D`, `Z` columns.

Other new dynamic functions such as `SORT` will also return a dynamic range.

Is there any function can select specific column of a range?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INDEX` function with arrays for the row/column arguments to return the relevant columns.

eg:

```
=FILTER(INDEX($A$1:$Z$1000,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A$1:$Z$1000)),{1,4,26}), $P$1:$P$1000="T1")
```

***EDIT:** At the request of @MátéJuhász, below is a screenshot with an example of a similar formula and the output, on a smaller scale*

```
=FILTER(INDEX($A$1:$N$7,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A$1:$N$7)),{1,4,10}), $K$1:$K$7="A")
```

[image]

Comment: This formula need to refer range `$A$1:$Z$1000` twice, is there a more simple way?

Comment: "If you set row_num or column_num to 0 (zero), INDEX returns the reference for the entire column or row, respectively"

Comment: @PaleNeutron What is your definition of "simpler". What is your goal?  Personally I would replace that range with a **Table** to take advantage of the auto-adjusting references. And replace `P1:P1000` with the structured reference referring to that column.  If you knew it would always be 1000 rows, you could replace the `ROWS(range(..` argument with `1000`.  You could use Named ranges (or the `LET` function -- not sure if that is simpler.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I've not been able to get that to work where the other argument is an array. Could you please elaborate how you solved that issue?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: your right using `0` doesn't work as expected. However I tried your solution and either that doesn't work for me. Could you please post some screenshots of output of your formula?

Comment: @MátéJuhász What does "doesn't work for me" mean?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Screenshot posted

Comment: @MátéJuhász, set row_num to 0 is nearly what I want, but sadly it can select only 1 column.  What a pity`=INDEX(A1:A10,0,1)` return a spilled range but `=INDEX(A1:A10,0,{1,3,5})` got only 3 values.